# cp -R source_path target_path vs cp -R source_path/* target_path

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2

what's the difference between

```
cp -R source_path target_path
```

vs

```
cp -R source_path/* target_path
```

I find the 2nd cmd works on my amazon linux system (red hat core), but I don't know why?

Comment: What error do you get for the 1st command?

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that the former creates `target_path/source_dir/*` while the latter `target_path/*`.  In other words, the first command copies files including the last directory in `source_path` and all the `.*` files in it, provided the are any.  The second command copies everything that does not start with `.` from `source_path` to `target_path`.

So my guess is that you really don't want to create the last directory from `source_path` in `target_path`, but instead copy all non-dot files from `source_path` directly there.

Comment: i just want to copy all files/subfolders in source_path (recursively) into the target_path. it's so strange, before the 1st one is working normally, but until today. unless i use the 2nd cmd. I guess it must be related with the linux environment.

Comment: @John Yin  Well, as I said, those commands are `not` equivalent.  It would maybe help if you showed the output you see or describe what exactly is not working.